# Compensation negotiation

Tags: salary, negotiation

could you tell me your opinion.

I was approached by HR from a different company who asked me some questions and suggested +10K for what I told him my salary is.
We met with him and 2 times with hiring company. It turned out that they decided to employ 2 persons instead of initial plan. I am the second one.
They came back and gave me an offer for -20K to what we agreed but suggested a car allowance instead of a company provided car (which gives me about +10K after car expenses). I said "it all good but your movement of -20K is very significant" can you make it probation only and increase after that. They said "ok", we give you another 5 grands if you pass probation.

So, if we forget about car allowance isn't is a too dramatic drop from initially discussed salary? If i agree to it now, would that be strange?

HR said, it was his mistake and he was not aware about company salary boundaries. He also assured me that another person gets 10K less. Problem is that I know this other guy and his salary later was higher than mine. So, I m not inclined to trust this HR.

Long story :)

Ok may be I have to clarify. My salary now is 83K + company provided car. HR offered 110K + company provided car. The best offer they have now is 95K after probation + 18K as car allowance. Which gives me (95+18-car expenses)=106 approximately. So from where I m now with my little 83K it is not bad. Taking into account that I m not well paid now. I from australia by the way. Our 83K are equal to 59K USD $.

Comment: My opinion? I'd walk away from this particular job and employer.

Comment: Is there a question here? or just looking for opinions?

Comment: Mates, thanks for answers. I was looking for someones opinion on the whole situation. If anyone experienced HR dropping his offer that low.

Comment: Flagging to close because the question is soliciting opinions, not answers.

Comment: Walk away and never even reply to them. Just forget about it.  And NEVER take benefits (car, etc) instead of cash.  All that counts is cash.

Comment: @Fattie That's a very short-sighted approach.

Comment: Not really.  You "seniority" is only ever explained by the "headline figure".  Nobody cares about benefits.  For someone starting out, you want to move through the tedious "junior - mid-level" positions as soon as humanly possible.  The only way to do that is, as aggressively as humanly possible advance your salary "by any and all means" - the headline figure.  Once you've got past that, sure, you can consider broader strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't really understand the car expenses thing.

- If this new job requires about $10k/year in car-related costs **and you are already paying those expenses at your current job**, then I guess this is a break-even for you.
- If this job requires an *increase* of $10k/year in car-related expenses, then giving you a $10k/year allowance is just a wash, so you still are taking a loss.

The way I see it, best case scenario (and it's an unlikely best), you break even.  Most likely, you are taking a $10k/year loss.

Frankly, for me to take a pay cut by changing jobs, I'd have to really hate my job.  That said, there is more to the world than money.

So it depends on really two things:

1. How motivated are you to start this new job?
2. How motivated are you to leave your current job?

I'm not entirely sure what your question actually is.  If it's how to get a higher salary from this new employer, I think you've already negotiated yourself down from that by saying the lower salary is fine with a probation period.

> He also assured me that another person gets 10K less. Problem is that I know this other guy and his salary later was higher than mine. So, I m not inclined to trust this HR.

Be careful comparing salaries between people!  It can drive the wrong behavior and you don't always know the accuracy of the data.  That said, as far as trust goes, I think you've answered your own question.  You don't trust HR because you caught them lying to you.  You haven't even accepted a job offer yet and already caught them lying in order to get you to settle for less money.  Personally, this one reason alone would make me reject it.  If they are dishonest already, do you think they will suddenly be honest once you join?  If they are doing a bait and switch on salary already, how do you know they won't just pay you less when you join?

My humble opinion is they are a cheap company and will continue to lie to you.  You deserve better.  The best bet you have to maximize your salary, with or without them, is to walk away.  If you decline the offer, either that's it and you go find a better job, or they will increase their offer to change your mind.  In my mind, either way: you win

Comment: If the questioner does accept this offer they should be very careful to make sure that the 'after probation' salary is written very clearly into the contract, along with exactly how long probation is.

Comment: Yes, absolutely